Reopening "How do idealists explain our lack of consciousness when we sleep?"
How do idealists explain our lack of consciousness when we sleep?
Nothing at all wrong with this question. It's a straightforward inquiry into what beliefs are held by a certain philosophical school of thought, which is always on-topic. Double Knot gave a good outline of how it may be answered with reference to Leibniz.
As before, get 4 reopen votes and tag me, and I will be the 5th.

I would suggest that people make a habit of leaving a comment explaining their close votes, as Jo Wehler did:

I vote to close this question due to lack of clarity: How do you define an idealist position? At least, please name some idealist philosophers; thanks.

I think this at least gives the asker a clear way to improve the question or ask a related one.
However, in this case I agree that the question is fundamentally clear; there are a set of philosophers who are broadly grouped as "metaphysical idealists" who hold that objects exist only if they are perceived in the mind. And this is a question about how they would respond to "OK but if you're dreaming, not aware of anything, what if a wolf bites your head off"

I like this idea

Also sometimes helps if you give the OP a chance to edit BEFORE the VTC. Generally, if something looks readily available to emending, a simple prefatory comment is enough to remediate the language without the hassle of closing, editing, and opening.

Yeah, closing because it needs editing has always bothered me on stack Exchange. They're really ought to be an intermediate state, which expresses a consensus that the question is not well formed and could be improved by taking actions x, gimmel, and thorn... The other solution, if it is obvious what the fix needs to be, is for the person raising the issue to propose an edit to address it rather than VTC. I am sometimes willing to make that effort on stacks which are less sensitive to exact wording; I would hesitate to do it here.

There is no philosophical school of thought called idealism. "Idealism" is a set of philosophies having not much in common with each other. The philosophies commonly listed ynder idealism have no single position on objective reality.
There are so many possible ways to close the question. Too broad applies, needs clarification applies, not about philosophy applies, depending on how the audience tries to make up for the lack of detail.

Double Knot gave a good outline of how it may be answered with reference to Leibniz.

The current shape of the question makes it impossible to know if that outline even remotely fits the question or not.
But if the answer is about how there is still brain activity during sleep, then the answer is not about philosophy, but about psychology or biology. Which is what the close voters seem to have focused on.
(Unless the asker was specifically asking about Leibnitz, in which case adding that to the question would take 5 seconds.)
It's unclear why begging the asker to invest 3 more minutes of their time to add the minimum of detail to their question to make it valid would constitute "harassment". It's less time for them than to read through all the answers that would not match what they had in mind.


What exactly is happening during sleep, or death or in general any time where we seem to not be conscious from an idealist’s perspective?

This is simply asking for an "idealist's" opinion about what happens during sleep.
When someone asks for your "perspective" they are asking for your opinion.
That is why I would vote to close.

Reopening "How do idealists explain our lack of consciousness when we sleep?"

A better question is :
Which idealist philosophers (if any) wrote about sleep or lack of consciousness?
All site users benefit from this question because the answer is a list of authors/papers that all users can read to determine their own answer rather then a spoon-fed user opinion.

I think you're getting fixated on wording, and I don't think that's useful. "From an idealist's perspective" means "how do idealist philosophers explain this" (i.e. what have they written about it.) You can suggest an edit to the title, and if the only issue is the small wording change I'd recommend suggesting an edit rather than VTC. That said, I also think your edit is worse. "which" is not an equivalent question.

All philosophy is opinion

@Syed I remember from the first time...https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5542/67687
